# flex xml children() method strange behaviour

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I have the following xml declaration:

```
public var reqData:XML = <root>
  <Requirement ID="REQ-GEN-0.1" title="exigence gen 1" description="blabla 01" testable="true"/>
  <RequirementSet ID="GUI REQ">
    <Requirement ID="REQ-GUI-1.1" title="exigence ihm 1" description="blabla 11" testable="true"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-GUI-1.2" title="exigence ihm 2" description="blabla 12" testable="false"/>
  </RequirementSet>
  <RequirementSet ID="PERF REQ">
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.1" title="exigence perf 1" description="blabla 21" testable="true"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.2" title="exigence perf 2" description="blabla 22" testable="false"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.3" title="exigence perf 3" description="blabla 23" testable="true"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.4" title="exigence perf 4" description="blabla 24" testable="false"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.5" title="exigence perf 5" description="blabla 25" testable="false"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.6" title="exigence perf 6" description="blabla 26" testable="false"/>
  </RequirementSet>
  <RequirementSet ID="BUS REQ">
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 1 REQ">
      <Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.1.1" title="exigence bus 1" description="blabla 311" testable="false"/>
      <Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.1.2" title="exigence bus 2" description="blabla 312" testable="true"/>
    </RequirementSet>
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 2 REQ">
      <Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.2.1" title="exigence bus3" description="blabla 321" testable="true"/>
    </RequirementSet>
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 3 REQ"/>
  </RequirementSet>
</root>;
```

I populated an advanced datagrid with this xml but the problem is that a requirement isn't detected: `<Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.2.1" title="exigence bus3" description="blabla 321" testable="true"/>`

I've overriden a method of the HierarchicalData class to see what happenned:

```
override public function canHaveChildren(node:Object):Boolean
        {
            if (node is XML && node != null){
                var xmlNode:XML = node as XML;
                trace("node:"+node);
                trace("node.children:"+node.children());
                trace("xmlNode.name:"+xmlNode.name());
                trace("xmlNode.localName:"+xmlNode.localName());
                trace("xmlNode.attributes:"+xmlNode.attributes());
                trace("xmlNode.attributes:"+xmlNode.nodeKind());
                trace("xmlNode.children():"+xmlNode.children());
                trace("xmlNode.children().length():"+xmlNode.children().length());

                if(xmlNode.children().length()>0){
                    var xmlNodeChildren:XMLList = xmlNode.children() as XMLList;
                    var xmlNodeFirstChild:XML = xmlNodeChildren[0];
                    trace("xmlNodeFirstChild:"+xmlNodeFirstChild);
                    trace("xmlNodeFirstChild.name():"+xmlNodeFirstChild.name());
                    trace("xmlNodeFirstChild.comments():"+xmlNodeFirstChild.comments());
                    trace("xmlNodeFirstChild.attributes():"+xmlNodeFirstChild.attributes());
                    trace("xmlNodeFirstChild.nodeKind():"+xmlNodeFirstChild.nodeKind());
                    trace("xmlNodeFirstChild.descendants():"+xmlNodeFirstChild.descendants());
                }


            }
```

And here is the result (console), that I just don't understand at all:

```
node:<RequirementSet ID="BUS 2 REQ">
  <Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.2.1" title="exigence bus3" description="blabla 321" testable="true"/>
</RequirementSet>
node.children:
xmlNode.name:RequirementSet
xmlNode.localName:RequirementSet
xmlNode.attributes:BUS 2 REQ
xmlNode.attributes:element
xmlNode.children():
xmlNode.children().length():1
xmlNodeFirstChild:
xmlNodeFirstChild.name():Requirement
xmlNodeFirstChild.comments():
xmlNodeFirstChild.attributes():REQ-BUS-3.2.1exigence bus3blabla 321true
xmlNodeFirstChild.nodeKind():element
xmlNodeFirstChild.descendants():
```

The node isn't detected by the children() method but it exists. The problem is that I can't look at the source code of XML.abc cause it isn't open-source. Can someone tell me what is happenning? Is it a bug or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node is picked up by the `children()` method just the way you intended, because otherwise the `length()` of `children()` would be 0.  What you have to understand is that `trace( node.children());` actually means `trace ( XMLList( node.children() ).toString());` - you are calling toString() on an XMLList - the output of which can have a number of different results, though obviously not very predictable ones:

```
var xml : XML = <node><child>MyText</child></node>;
trace ( xml.children () ); 
// => MyText

xml = <node><child value="MyText" /></node>;
trace ( xml.children () ); 
// => nothing

xml = <node><child key="myKey" id="1" value="MyText" /></node>;
trace ( xml.children () ); 
// => nothing

xml = <node><child id="1" key="text">MyText</child></node>;
trace ( xml.children () ); 
// => MyText

xml = <node><child id="1">MyText<child id="2">MyOtherText</child></child></node>;
trace ( xml.children () ); 
// => <child id="1">MyText<child id="2">MyOtherText</child></child>
```

To make sure you get the full xml of your child node, try:

```
var childXML : String = node.children().length() > 0 ? node.children()[0].toXMLString():"empty");
trace("node.child#0:"+ childXML);
// output: 
// node.child#0:<Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.2.1" title="exigence bus3" description="blabla 321" testable="true"/>
```